# How to revert LLVM to older version on LINUX?

Tags: linux, version, llvm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, uninstallation

I have installed LLVM on my WSL.But Now I need an older version of LLVM.
How can I revert LLVM to old version?
the commands I used to install it:

```
git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
cd llvm-project
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm
make
```

And my `llvm-as --version` outputs:

```
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 11.0.0git
  DEBUG build with assertions.
  Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: skylake
```

Can I just remove the dir `build`?

Answer (score 1):

The `llvm-project` repository contains tags for almost every LLVM release. Just checkout them using git:

```
cd llvm-project
git checkout -t origin/llvmorg-3.8.0
```

It is advised to remove `build` dir and configure&build from scratch.